# push content to stacked portion of an included view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `header.blade.php` view as this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
<head>
    SomeThins come here
</head>
<body>

@stack('user_navbar')
```

And I have a `default.blade.php` like this :

```
@include('main.includes.header')

    @push('user_navbar')
        The user Navbar is here 
    @endpush
    
    @yield('content')
@include('main.includes.footer')
```

And there is a `main.blade.php` like this :

```
@extends('main.default')

@section('content')
    Some Content is here
@endsection
```

I want to push the `user_navbar` content to the `header` view that is included itself. But nothing shows for that.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact file design you have in mind but why not have the following:

header.blade.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
<head>
    SomeThings come here
</head>
<body>

@yield('content')

@stack('user_navbar')

@include('main.includes.footer')
```

and

default.blade.php

```html
@include('main.includes.header')

@push('user_navbar')
    The user Navbar is here 
@endpush

@yield('content')
```

This way, when the default.blade.php file is rendered, the content pushed to the user_navbar stack will be displayed within the @stack('user_navbar') directive that is included in the header.blade.php file.